# How to grep accurate match

Tags: linux, grep

I have a file as follows:

```
SD
SD SD
SD W
```

I want to match the `SD` used grep only for the first line except the second and third lines. How does it?

The resulted I want to match in first line here just an example. So, based on line namber just like `grep 1` or `grep -w 1` are all not better. I want to know is how to distinguish match `SD` and `SD SD` or `SD W`?
Thanls.

Comment: something line this - `grep -n "SD" <filename> | grep 1`

Comment: What if the first `SD` is on the second line?

Comment: @ZeekHuge That will find `SD` on lines 10-19 too...

Comment: maybe then `grep -n "SD" <filename> | grep -w 1`

Comment: The resulted I want to match in first line here just a example. So, grep 1 or grep -w 1 are all not better. I want to know is how to distinguish match ``SD`` and ``SD SD`` or ``SD W``?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
grep ',SD,' filename
```

Or do you really just grep on the first line?

```
head -n1 filename | grep 'SD'
```

Comment: Actually, This is not the result I want.

Comment: @zhongpingxu: Then, please, be more specific.

Comment: `grep ',SD,' filename` in @choroba 's answer should distinguish the between `SD` and `SD SD` and `SD W`. What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `-m` option for `grep`,

`-m NUM` for grep: matching  lines

```
$ grep -m 1 "SD" file
AS,SD,GFFG
```

Comment: Actually, This is not the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
grep -E "^SD$" file
```

In English: *"Find the line that starts with (=`^`) the letter 'S' and ends with (=`$`) the letter 'D'".*

This returns:

```
SD
```

But if there were two identical lines, it would return both of them.
So if you want to limit the number of matches, you could use the `-m` flag.

> -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
>                 Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the  input  is
>                 standard  input  from a regular file, and NUM matching lines are
>                 output, grep ensures that the standard input  is  positioned  to
>                 just  after the last matching line before exiting, regardless of
>                 the presence of trailing context lines.
>                 ...